# Passing multiple objects to pug (jade) not working

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm trying to pass two different dictionaries to my jade template like so

```
res.render('template/templateOne', {
     title: 'cool title',
     dictOne:dictUno,
     dictTwo:dictDos
});
```

but for whatever reason the second object does not show up in the template. if I do a console log from the template it is there however whenever I try and set a variable from something in the second dictionary it will not populate. It will populate from the first dict just fine though

here is the jade

```
extends ../panels/panelLayout

block content

  section.content-header
          h1=dictOne.value  
          ol.breadcrumb
            li
              a(href='#')
                i.fa.fa-dashboard
                |  Home
            li.active=dictOne.value
  section.content
    .row
      .col-sm-4
        .box.box-primary
            .box-header.with-border
              h3.box-title Client Info
                |
                .box-body
                  strong
                    |  Client Name
                  p.text-muted #{dictTwo.value}
                  hr
                  strong
                    |  Address
                  p.text-muted=dictTwo.value
              hr
              strong
                |  City
              p.text-muted=dictTwo.value
              hr
              .box-footer
```

Comment: How are you using it in the template file?

Answer (score 0):

solved, I was not parsing my mongo query properly and was returning an array instead of a dictionary. Thank you for your assistance